# How to presentViewController in share extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I am customising the share extension in iOS.

I create a button and want to presentViewController,

but the self.extensionContext not have presentViewController method.

In the main app we can use below the code to presentViewController.

```
 [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

completion:nil];

How to present view controller in self.extensionContext

I can't use

```
 [self.extensionContext  presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

How can I present view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller in which you want to present a view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:true completion:nil];
```